# how to echo strings and variable in laravel 5.1 blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am using this code inside my `PHP` file:

```
university.blade.php

{{ url( $universities->universityName.'/students') }}" >
```

The problem is that displays just `http://localhost:8000/students`, not the value of variable. So what is the solution?

Comment: Can i see your blade code?

Comment: Probably `$universities->universityName` is empty, kindly include the controller that presents `university.blade.php` Also try `{!! url( $universities->universityName.'/students') !!}`

Comment: **NOTE:** `{{}}` is for vers laravel 4 while `{!! !!}` is for the newest version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `$universities->universityName` is empty

Lets assume your controller looks like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers

use App\University; // I assume this is your model

class UniversityController extends Controller{

     public function index()
     {
         $universities = Univeristy::all();

         return view('universities', compact('universities'));
     }

}
```

Then later in your `universities.blade.php`

```
<a href="{!! url("{$univerisity->universityName}/students") !!}">Students</a>
```

or you can check if `$universities->universityName` is empty, if it doesn't print the URL means its empty.

```
@if(!$universities || !$universities->universityName)
    <a href="{!! url("{$univerisity->universityName}/students") !!}">Students</a>
@endif
```

Comment: Try `{!! url("{$univerisity->university Name}/students") !!}`

Answer (score 2):

As it seems you're passing some parameter in the url.

I assume that you want to print those parameter in your view

Here i wrote an example route, controller with view for your understanding.

**Step 1 :** Write a route method

```
Route::get('get/{id}', 'publicController@get');
```

**Step 2 :** Write a function inside your controller

```
public function get($id)
    {
        return view('get')->with('id', $id);
    }
```

Now you're returning the parameter that you passed to the view

**Step 3 :** Show in your View

Inside your view you can simply echo it using

```
{{ $id }}
```

So If you have this in your url

`http://localhost/yourproject/get/14`

Then it will print `14`

Hope this helps you

Comment: It should be as simple as `{{$yourfirstvariable.$id.$yourvariable}}`