# How can print Laravel variable with echo

Tags: php, laravel, echo

```
<?php echo Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['/cart/add/'. "{{$product->product_id }}"]] )?>
<?php echo Form::button('Agregar al Carro', ['class' => 'btn-u btn-u-sea-shop btn-u-lg', 'type' => 'submit']) ?>
<?php echo Form::close()  ?>
```

I need to print the variable `$product` in a template.

Comment: Search stackoverflow's another answers similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666015/how-to-echo-strings-and-variable-in-laravel-5-1-blade

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel's Blade: how can I set variables in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002626/6521116)

Comment: Tried [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)?

Comment: The solution was

Comment: <?php echo Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url' => ["/cart/add/{{product_id}}"]] )?>
                    <?php echo Form::button('Agregar al Carro', ['class' => 'btn-u btn-u-sea-shop btn-u-lg', 'type' => 'submit']) ?>
                    <?php echo Form::close()  ?>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can echo it with php like:

```
<?php echo $product->product_id ?>
```

and in blade syntax like:

```
{{$product->product_id}}
```

and in your case it should be like:

```
'url' => [ '/cart/add/'. $product->product_id ]
```

only concatenation is required here

Comment: <?php echo Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'url' => ['/cart/add/'. $product->product_id ]] )?>

Comment: Undefined variable: product (View: /

Comment: That means `product` variable is not passed from controller to view and you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

you can print variable like that in blade

> {{$product}}

see for more details in laravel official [site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: I'm using a template with php

Comment: ok .see @Mayank Pandeyz's  answer for template. thanks